# Why can't hexagonal lattice be body-centered or face-centered?

Tags: symmetry, crystals

There are 14 bravais lattices, extending 7 primitive lattice by optionally adding points on base centers, face centers or body centers for 7 crystal systems. I know some combination are not allowed, e.g., adding base center points in simple hexagonal lattice disturb the 6-fold symmetry, base centered tetrahegal lattice can be taken as original simple tetrahegal lattice. But when confronted body centered and face centered hexagonal lattice, i don't understand why they don't exist.

Hope someone can show me why there can't be.

Comment: In the 14 Bravais lattices, the view from every point is identical - there are no A vs B atom positions. If you draw a 'body centered' or 'face centered' hexagonal lattice, you will see that not all points are the same. You can tell if you are on the base hexagonal lattice or on those additions. It is no longer a Bravais lattice.